# React-native app crashes when installing fuse.js with transform error

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, babeljs, fuse.js

I'm trying to install fuse.js in a react-native app. It should work fine seeing as it doesn't seem that fuse depends on the DOM whatsoever. However, after installing and even after restarting the packager, I get:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4604): SyntaxError: TransformError: /Users/<redacted>/node_modules/fuse.js/dist/fuse.js: Unknown plugin "babel-plugin-add-module-exports" specified in "/Users/<redacted>/node_modules/fuse.js/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/Users/<redacted>/node_modules/fuse.js"
```

This is in the ios simulator, running react-native 0.42.3, node 7.0.0 on OSX.

I've never dealt with babel errors in react-native. Is this a bug or perhaps just an issue on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue and got it resolved by installing the missing npm modules:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 \
babel-preset-stage-2 \
babel-plugin-add-module-exports`

Comment: This was one solution. Initially I actually just removed the bablerc from the repo but this is certainly better.